# How can I collect the vowels and consonants of a script without collecting empty spaces?

Tags: python

I was looking to see how I would be able to collect the consonants without counting any blank spaces in between words.

```
def main():
string=input("Enter a string here: ")
vowels=0
consonants=0

for i in string:
    if(i=='a'or i=='e'or i=='i'or i=='o'or i=='u' or i=='A' or i=='E'or i=='I' or i=='O' or i=='U'):
        vowels=vowels+1
    else:
        consonants=consonants+1


    
print('The string you have entered includes', vowels,'vowels and',consonants,'consonants!')
```

main()

Comment: How does this code relate to what you want to do?

Comment: This is the question I am asked in class: Write a program with a function that accepts a string as an argument
and returns the number of vowels that the string contains.
The application should have another function that accepts a string
as an argument and returns the number of consonants that the string contains.
The application should let the user enter a string and should display
the number of vowels and the number of consonants it contains. What I am looking for is to collect the vowels and consonants without collecting the blank spaces in between the lines.

Comment: This is an example: Enter a string here: Hi, how are you. Output = There are 6 vowels and 5 consonants

Answer (score 0):

This code should collect vowels already. You can use `elif(i=" ")` to check for the spaces and use `continue()` to make loop skip them, and then `else` would be consonants (in case your user won't enter something like "][3||0!").

One way to make your life easier is to use `.lower()` method - this way you'd turn all the input to lowercase letters and you can cut your `if (i="a"....)` condition in half

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to solve this.

The reason you are currently counting characters you do not want, is because you used `else`, but just because a character is not a vowel, does not mean it is a consonant.

You could use `elif` and check for all the consonants, but that would be a long and ugly condition.

Instead, you can use [`isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) to make sure your current character is a letter first, then check if it is a vowel or a consonant.

```
vow = 'aeiou'

...

for i in string:
    if i.isalpha():
        if i.lower() in vow:
            vowels += 1
        else:
            consonants += 1
```

Note, that your current code does not comply with the requirements in your homework, but I will leave that part to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty close. You are correctly counting the vowels. If you add to your else block a check to make sure you have a letter, then you are good to go.

```
else:
    if i in string.ascii_letters: #you may need to import string
        #now you know that i is a letter, but not a vowel
        consonants += 1
```

Also, your vowels check can be simplified to

```
if i in 'aeiouAEIOU':
```

it does the same thing, but will probably be easier to read.